# Join condition on a concatenated columns from both left and right table

Tags: sql, mysql, google-bigquery

Suppose Nick has poorly designed a database consisting of two tables 'A' and 'B'.

There are 3 columns available in table 'A':

| Column Name | Datatype |
| --- | --- |
| natural_key | String |
| department | String |
| employee_name | String |

The column 'natural_key' in table 'A' is stored from an abstract source but we know that it is the concatenation of 'employee_id' and 'department'.

Sample data in Table  A:

| natural_key | employee_name | department |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5001Marketing | John | Marketing |
| 6789Sales | Mary | Sales |

There is only one column available in table 'B':

| Column Name | Datatype |
| --- | --- |
| employee_id | String |

Sample data in table B:

| employee_id |
| --- |
| 6789 |
| 8001 |

Nick wishes to perform an INNER JOIN on these two tables. But since he does not have any matching columns, he has written below query:

```
SELECT 
  B.employee_id,
  A.employee_name
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.natural_key = CONCAT(B.employee_id, A.department);
```

Questions:

1. Is there anything wrong with the above join condition, keeping aside the poor design of DB, concatenation doesn't allow join optimization, two employee_ids might belong to same department and result in incorrect data?
2. Would the join result in cross join i.e. first it would concat each row of table B to all the rows of table A and then perform a join?

Comment: Sounds like you've got a good handle on what's wrong here. For (2) MySQL and BigQuery are two totally different things. You'll have to look at the explain plan to figure out what it opted for. I think, in general the natural key should be delimited in some way like '|' or something. So I'd usually extract the token associated with the employee name instead of concatenate. Still has pretty much all the same problems, but figure it gives the optimizer a fighting chance to avoid the product join.

Comment: I don't see how you can get incorrect results. If there are two employees in the same department, they'll each have their own rows in table A. The problem here is poor normalization: an employee's name shouldn't depend on which department they're in. And redundancy: the department name is in the `natural_key` and `department` columns.

Comment: I don`t see a direct problem however I'm just not comfortable with contacting values from the 2 tables on the join condition. I`m not sure how it works when it comes to efficiency.  I would rather use regex expressions to extract the numeric part of the natural_key. Adding an example below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can use `regex`

```
WITH A AS (
    SELECT '5001Marketing' AS natural_key, 'John' AS employee_name, 'Marketing' AS department
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '6789Sales', 'Mary', 'Sales'
),
B AS (
    SELECT '6789' AS employee_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT '8001'
)
SELECT 
    B.employee_id,
    A.employee_name
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON B.employee_id = REGEXP_SUBSTR(A.natural_key, '^[0-9]+')
```